# warning using mockito-android

Tags: android, mockito, powermockito

I got this warning using mockito

> You included the 'mockito-android' dependency in a non-Android environment.
>   The Android mock maker was disabled. You should only include the latter in your 'androidTestCompile' configuration
>   If disabling was a mistake, you can set the 'org.mockito.mock.android' property to 'true' to override this detection.

where could I set the property that the message say?

what is this error about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that for testImplementation we should use mockito-core and for androidTestImplementation mockito-android

[Mockito Documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#0.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mockito-android` as `implementation`(sample use case: if you are building a library for tests) then set the property as a System property inside your `@Before` method to let `mockito` know that the dependency is not added as `implementation` by mistake

```
 @Before
 open fun setUp() {
    System.setProperty("org.mockito.mock.android", "true")
 }
```